# Iphone Spell check

Tags: iphone, cpu-word

Is it possible to get access to a word library in the Iphone.  I need to be able to check to see if user input matches a real word.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In iOS SDK 3.2+, create an instance of `UITextChecker` and call `rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:range:startingAt:wrap:language:`.